# Android application listed as compatible with Sony Xperia S but still filtered from google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an Android application and some users are complaining that it is listed as not compatible with Sony Xperia S. According to the developer console Xperia S (LT26i) is listed as compatible. Do anyone know of any reason why the app is still filtered from google play?

I have seen people reporting problems with big apk files. This app is about 20Mb in size, with the largest file being 14Mb. Quite a bit but not enough to cause problems I think...

Here is the output from aapt dump badging:

```
package: name='no.bouvet.nrkut' versionCode='4' versionName='1.0'
sdkVersion:'4'
targetSdkVersion:'13'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
application-label:'UT.no'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/utno_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/utno_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/utno_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/utno_launcher.png'
application: label='UT.no' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/utno_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='no.bouvet.nrkut.MainActivity'  label='UT.no' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.wifi'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
main
other-activities
search
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="no.bouvet.nrkut"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          android:versionCode="4"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="4"
            android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <instrumentation
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            android:functionalTest="true"
            android:handleProfiling="false"
            android:label="tests"
            android:targetPackage="no.bouvet.nrkut">
    </instrumentation>

    <application
            android:name="MainApplication"
            android:icon="@drawable/utno_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.NearbyActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MapActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AboutActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ToplistsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.CoresiteActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.FavouritesActivity"/>

        <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".activity.SearchableActivity"/>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Although supports any-density is true, if this helps in anyway pixel density in Xperia S is 342 approx. Can you post your Android Manifest here.

Comment: I just received an email from one of my users, reporting the same issue. App not compatible with Xperia S, even though the Developer Console says otherwise. I'll report back here if I find a solution...

Comment: Have added the AndroidManifest.xml file. See that it contains <uses-library "android.test.runner">, could this be the problem? (Will check next time we update the app, in a few days)